# normalized point coordinates in undistortPoints function

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, perspective, perspectivecamera

In undistortPoints function from OpenCV, the documentations says that

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints

*where undistort() is an approximate iterative algorithm that estimates the normalized original point coordinates out of the normalized distorted point coordinates (“normalized” means that the coordinates do not depend on the camera matrix).*

It seems that the normalized point coordinates is obtained by adding 1 to the third coordinate. What does normalized point coordinates means? How can it be used for?

In the above, there are two lines

x" = (u - cx)/fx

y" = (v - cy)/fy

Is there one term for the coordinates(x'', y'')?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Is there one term for the coordinates (x", y")", but if you mean what do they physically represent, then they are the coordinates of the image point (u, v) on the image plane expressed in the camera coordinate system (origin at the centre of projection, x-axis to the right, y-axis down, z-axis pointing out towards the scene and perpendicular to the image plane), whereas (u,v) are the coordinates of the image point relative to the origin at the top left corner of the image plane (x-axis to the right, y-axis down). All quantities are expressed in pixels.

The output of the undistortPoints function are normalised coordinates, which means that the points returned in the dst parameter have their (x", y") coordinates between 0 and 1 (not shown in the equations you presented, but is the output of the internally called undistort function within undistortPoints).

2D coordinates (whether normalised or not) that have a 1 inserted as the third coordinate are known as homogenous coordinates. The same can be done for 3D coordinates by inserting a 1 into the 4th element. Homogenous coordinates are useful because they allow certain operations to be represented as a simple linear equation whereas their non-homogenous equivalent may not be as straightforward.